# jQuery - how to add navigation to simple gallery

Tags: jquery, navigation, gallery

I've got another problem with gallery script

```
var tag = $('a.click [rel="gall"]');
$(tag).live('click', function() {
    $('body').append('<div class="curtain" />').append('<div class="box" />').css({'overflow':'hidden'});
    $('.box').css({'width': '400px', 'left': '400px', 'top': '50%', 'margin-left': '-200px', 'margin-top':'-200px'}).append('<a class="close" style="margin-left: 406px" title="close" ></a>').append('<div class="image" />').append('<p />');
    $('.close').click(function() {
        $('body').removeAttr('style');
        $('.curtain, .box').hide();
    })

    for(var i=0; i < $(this).find('img').length; i++) {
        var width = $('.image').width();
        $('.box p').html('<b>'+$(this).attr('title')+'</b><br />'+$(this).find('img').attr('alt'));
        $('.box .image').append('<img src="'+$(this).attr('href')+'" alt="image" />');
    }
    return false;
});
```

I'm wondering how to add navigation to this if there is more links with the same rel attribute?

Can tell me how to do this, how to count all `<a href="#" rel="gall" >` with img and if there is more than one display prev next button ?

every answer counts :)

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460442/how-to-add-next-prev-buttons-to-a-slideshow

Comment: Can someone tell me why this script doesnt work under IE8> ??

Comment: no errors, it don't append any div or anything

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle with your code?

Comment: sorry jsfiddle doesn't work for me so i've done this in [http://jsbin.com/](http://jsbin.com/opiriy/2/edit#javascript,html,live)

Comment: sorry that doesn't work as a jQ plugin